# OpenStack DevStack Installation Ubuntu 16.04

Tags: 16.04, python, openstack

I'm trying to do an installation of OpenStack DevStack on a clean installation of Ubuntu 16.04 Desktop.

The Setup stops when it comes to the following error:

```
+inc/python:pip_install:359                env http_proxy= https_proxy= no_proxy= PIP_FIND_LINKS= SETUPTOOLS_SYS_PATH_TECHNIQUE=rewrite /opt/stack/requirements/.venv/bin/pip install -c /opt/stack/requirements/upper-constraints.txt -U pbr
env: ‘/opt/stack/requirements/.venv/bin/pip’: No such file or directory
```

I also see lots of warnings about Python versions:

```
Ignoring asyncio: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring asyncio: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring dnspython3: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring dnspython3: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring mypy: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring mypy: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring jeepney: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring jeepney: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring SecretStorage: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring SecretStorage: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring typed-ast: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring typed-ast: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Ignoring pyldap: markers 'python_version == "3.4"' don't match your environment
Ignoring pyldap: markers 'python_version == "3.5"' don't match your environment
Requirement already satisfied: systemd-python===234 in /usr/local/lib/python2.7/dist-packages (from -c /opt/stack/requirements/upper-constraints.txt (line 401))
You are using pip version 9.0.3, however version 10.0.1 is available.
You should consider upgrading via the 'pip install --upgrade pip' command.
```

I'm running Python 2.7.12 and 3.5.1-3

I setup the user with `sudo useradd -d /bin/bash -d /opt/stack -m stack`

Thanks

Comment: I have the exact same error.

Answer (score 6):

Somewhere virtualenv failed to install pip, and other python things, into ~/requirements/.venv/ . Someone with better understanding of DevStack should solve this properly, but in the meantime manually running the following command solved the problem for me:

```
stack@mymachine:~/devstack$ virtualenv ../requirements/.venv/
```

Comment: This solved the problem for me too. However, did you have an SQL connection issue later during the stack.sh run ?

Comment: Edit: This doesn't happen with Ubuntu 16.04, I was previously using the new 18.04.

Comment: This solved my problem on Ubuntu 18.04, thanks!

Answer (score 0):

After some digging around I found that running the following, before the script made everything work OK.  Just a reminder that I'm using 16.04:

```
sudo apt-get install git python-pip
sudo pip install --upgrade pip
```

It's interesting as none of the guides mention this, and I assume the script is supposed to install this. I wonder what has changed since the original 16.04 release?

I still get all the Python warnings (any idea why?), but I now have a working DevStack environment.

Answer (score 0):

Just adding some details, You might get some permission denied error while using the `virtualenv` command.
So first give `777` permission to the directory:

```
$ sudo chmod 777 /opt/stack/requirements/.venv
$ virtualenv /opt/stack/requirements/.venv/
```